# Effect of Angels amputating wings?

Tags: religion, inspiration, mythology, lucifer

In several movies, series and books, Angels living on earth have amputated their wings - or had them amputated:

- The Hush book-series by Becca Fitzpatrick
- Lucifer comic-series
- Lucifer TV-series (loosely based on the comics)
- Legion movie
- ( The Prophecy/God's Army movie + sequels ? )

...and probably many others.

In "Hush" it's fallen angels - those who sided with Lucifer - who had their wings amputated, before being cast down to earth.  (Well, I think... I've honestly haven't read the whole book-series.)  In the "Legion" movie it appears the angel cuts off his wings so he can defy God, by trying to save humanity.  In "Lucifer" (TV-show... I haven't read the comics, but I think it's explained better there), Lucifer gets his wings amputated, seemingly partly to gain free will (so he can leave Hell and remain on Earth), and partly to spite God.

I was therefor wondering if there are some "religious" sources - the Bible, the Apocryphs, The Divine Comedy, Angel-myths - that establish this, that a wingless Angel got free will, or at least can somewhat defy God?  Apart from this and punishment (ie. "Fallen Angels"), are there any other "common" reason and effects of angels losing/amputating/getting amputated wings?

Comment: *Dogma* is a pretty popular, modern example as well. But, I suspect that the answers you are looking for are going to wind up making this question off-topic.

Comment: @Ellesedil It's about real-world sources of SF&F tropes. Isn't that on-topic?

Comment: @Adeptus if you take a look at Meta, there's recent discussion about answers that include religion. I'm not sure if answers to this question would be appropriate. I haven't raised a flag; I'm simply stating the possibility it could be an issue.

Comment: @Ellesedil That's about treating religion *as fiction*, which this question isn't doing.

Comment: This question is asking for references from religious material, which is not permitted.

Comment: @motoDrizzt No, I'm not really... First off, I'm after the *mythology* aspect, not the "religious" aspect.  Yes, some of it would come from the Bible, but it's no difference from fantasy-books based on Norse gods (eg. Thor) or Greek, Roman or Egyptian gods (eg. Percy Jackson).  Second, I suspect much will come from non-religious sources, ie. stories and fiction just loosely based on The Bible/religion (eg. Dantes "The Divine Comedy").  Simply put; I'm looking for a common source for "why angels amputate wings" - what's it's bases?

Comment: @BaardKopperud:  "the Bible, the Apocryphs, [The Divine Comedy], Angel-myths" Three out of four are religious texts. And Angels are a religious concept. Your question as it stand encourage people to use a religious text as a reference for their answer, and as you can read in Meta this is currently considered rude for people, even if it's a good and literally interesting question over the inspiration for some common concepts found in SF&F, as Richard has pointed out "this is SF&F, we speak only about fiction".

Comment: @BaardKopperud: you should thus reword your question in something like "what is the origin in fiction (if there is one) of the concept of angel's amputating wings?"

Comment: Or you could ask on the Christianity SE. But I'll tell you in advance, there's not going to much about the in Christian texts. Popular culture angels have diverged a long way from Christian ones.

Comment: If you are asking about mythology, maybe it would be better to take it to [Mythology SE](http://mythology.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @BaardKopperud we try to avoid both religious and mythological works here, because there is very contentious debate over which (if any) of those things count as "science fiction" or "fantasy". We do have dedicated Stack Exchange sites that focus on those topics.

Comment: Can someone migrate this to Mythology SE?